# Spring Boot repository not working during testing

Tags: java, spring, database, spring-boot, java-8

I've searched Google and SO answers and have tried many variations with no luck. I'm trying to enable integration testing for my Spring Boot endpoints for the past few days now. Here are the details:

The error is a NullPointerException found in the EnclosureController class (where I've marked the object in a comment with NULL)

If there exists a more efficient way to perform integration testing, as compared to MockMvc, I'm very open to suggestions.

TestClass (in root.package.test )

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@WebMvcTest(EnclosureController.class)
public class EnclosureControllerTest {

@Autowired
private MockMvc mvc;

@MockBean
private EnclosureRepository enclosureRepository;

//static final strings for Enclosure initialization

@Test
public void createEnclosureAPI() throws Exception
{
    mvc.perform( MockMvcRequestBuilders
            .post("/enclosure")
            .header("Authorization", "TEST")
            .content(asJsonString(new Enclosure(ENCLOSURE_TITLE, ENCLOSURE_LOCATION, DIMENSIONAL_UNITS, ENCLOSURE_LENGTH, ENCLOSURE_WIDTH, ENCLOSURE_HEIGHT)))
            .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
            .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
            .andExpect(status().isCreated())
            .andDo(print())
            .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.jsonPath("$.enclosureId").exists());
}
}
```

EnclosureController (I removed the authentication checks since the error pertains to the repo)

```
@RestController
public class EnclosureController {

final
private EnclosureRepository repository;

@Autowired
public EnclosureController(EnclosureRepository repository) {
    this.repository = repository;
}

@RequestMapping(value = {"/enclosure"},
        method = RequestMethod.POST,
        consumes = "application/json",
        produces = APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
@ResponseBody
@Async("asyncExecutor")
public CompletableFuture<Enclosure> createEnclosure(
        @Valid @RequestBody Enclosure request,
        @RequestHeader(value = "Authorization") String auth,
        HttpServletResponse response
) {

    //NULL on repository (Optional is never returned. NullPointerExcep thrown on repository.save)
    int enclosureId = Optional.of(repository.save(request)).orElse(new Enclosure(0)).getEnclosureId();

    if (enclosureId > 0)
        response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_CREATED);

    return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(repository.findByEnclosureId(enclosureId));

}

}
@RequestMapping(value = {"/enclosure/{id}"},
        method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
@Async("asyncExecutor")
public CompletableFuture<Enclosure> getSingleEnclosure(
        @PathVariable("id") int id,
        @RequestHeader(value = "Authorization") String auth,
        HttpServletResponse response
) {

    return  CompletableFuture.completedFuture(repository.findByEnclosureId(id));

}
```

Repository

```
@Repository
public interface EnclosureRepository extends CrudRepository<Enclosure, Integer> {
Enclosure findByEnclosureId(Integer enclosureId);
List<Enclosure> findAll();
}
```

RepositoryImpl (for bean decleration. Note removed unneeded methods for this post)

```
public class EnclosureRepositoryImpl implements EnclosureRepository {

private static ConcurrentHashMap<Integer, Optional<Enclosure>> repo = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
private static AtomicInteger maxId = new AtomicInteger();

@Override
public Enclosure findByEnclosureId(Integer enclosureId) {
    return repo.get(enclosureId).orElse(new Enclosure());
}

@Override
public Enclosure save(Enclosure entity) {

    repo.put(maxId.incrementAndGet(), Optional.of(entity));

    return repo.get(maxId).orElse(new Enclosure());
}

@Override
public Optional<Enclosure> findById(Integer integer) {
    return repo.get(integer);
}

@Override
public boolean existsById(Integer integer) {
    return repo.containsKey(integer);
}
}
```

Application

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
```

Configuration

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = {
    "root.package.model.repository"
})
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableAsync
public class BeanConfig {

@Override
@Bean(name = "asyncExecutor")
public Executor getAsyncExecutor() {
    ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
    executor.setCorePoolSize(3);
    executor.setMaxPoolSize(100);
    executor.setQueueCapacity(100);
    executor.setThreadNamePrefix("AGMSpringAsyncThread-");
    executor.initialize();

    return executor;
}

@Bean
JpaTransactionManager transactionManager(EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory) {
    JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
    transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory);
    return transactionManager;
}

@Bean
LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory(DataSource dataSource,
                                                            Environment env) {
    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactoryBean = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
    entityManagerFactoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource);
    entityManagerFactoryBean.setJpaVendorAdapter(new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter());
    entityManagerFactoryBean.setPackagesToScan("io.colby.model.repository");

    Properties jpaProperties = new Properties();

    //Configures the used database dialect. This allows Hibernate to create SQL
    //that is optimized for the used database.
    jpaProperties.put("hibernate.dialect", env.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.dialect"));

    //Specifies the action that is invoked to the database when the Hibernate
    //SessionFactory is created or closed.
    jpaProperties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto",
            env.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto")
    );

    //Configures the naming strategy that is used when Hibernate creates
    //new database objects and schema elements
    jpaProperties.put("hibernate.ejb.naming_strategy",
            env.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.ejb.naming_strategy")
    );

    //If the value of this property is true, Hibernate writes all SQL
    //statements to the console.
    jpaProperties.put("hibernate.show_sql",
            env.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.show_sql")
    );

    //If the value of this property is true, Hibernate will format the SQL
    //that is written to the console.
    jpaProperties.put("hibernate.format_sql",
            env.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.format_sql")
    );

    entityManagerFactoryBean.setJpaProperties(jpaProperties);

    return entityManagerFactoryBean;
}

@Bean(destroyMethod = "close")
DataSource dataSource(Environment env) {
    HikariConfig dataSourceConfig = new HikariConfig();
    dataSourceConfig.setDriverClassName(env.getRequiredProperty("db.driver"));
    dataSourceConfig.setJdbcUrl(env.getRequiredProperty("db.url"));
    dataSourceConfig.setUsername(env.getRequiredProperty("db.username"));
    dataSourceConfig.setPassword(env.getRequiredProperty("db.password"));

    return new HikariDataSource(dataSourceConfig);
}

@Bean
public EnclosureRepository enclosureRepository(){
    return new EnclosureRepositoryImpl();
}
}
```

Enclosure

```
@Component
@Entity
@Table(name="enclosure")
public class Enclosure {


@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "enclosure_id", nullable = false, updatable = false)
@JsonProperty("enclosure-id")
private Integer enclosureId;

@Column(name = "title")
@Size(max = 255)
@NotBlank
private String title;

@Column(name = "location")
@Size(max = 255)
private String location;

@Column(length = 25, name = "dimension_units")
@Size(max = 25)
@JsonProperty("dimension-units")
private String dimensionUnits;

@CreationTimestamp
@Column(nullable = false, name = "insert_timestamp")
@JsonProperty("created-date-time")
private LocalDateTime insertTimestamp;

@UpdateTimestamp
@Column(name = "update_timestamp")
@JsonProperty("last-updated-date-time")
private LocalDateTime updateTimestamp;


@Column(length = 5, precision = 2)
private double length;
@Column(length = 5, precision = 2)
private double width;
@Column(length = 5, precision = 2)
private double height;

public Enclosure(String title,
                 String location,
                 String dimensionUnits,
                 double length, double width, double height) {
    this.title = title;
    this.location = location;
    this.dimensionUnits = dimensionUnits;
    this.length = length;
    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;
}

public Enclosure(int enclosureId){
    this.enclosureId = enclosureId;
}

public Enclosure(){

}
//Getters and setters...
```

Directory Tree

```
.
└── main
    ├── java
    │   └── root
    │       └── package
    │           ├── Application.java
    │           ├── configuration
    │           │   ├── BeanConfig.java
    │           ├── model
    │           │   ├── entity
    │           │   │   ├── Enclosure.java
    │           │   └── repository
    │           │       ├── EnclosureRepository.java
    │           │       ├── EnclosureRepositoryImpl.java
    │           ├── routes
    │           │   ├── enclosure
    │           │   │   └── controller
    │           │   │       └── EnclosureController.java
    │           └── test
    │               └── routes
    │                   └── enclosure
    │                       └── EnclosureControllerTest.java
    ├── resources
    │   ├── application.properties
    └── test
        └── java
```

application.properties

```
 #Database Configuration
    db.driver=org.h2.Driver
    db.url=jdbc:h2:mem:datajpa
    db.username=sa
    db.password=

    spring.jackson.default-property-inclusion=non_null

    # Details for our datasource
    spring.datasource.url = jdbc:postgresql://host/db
    spring.datasource.username = user
    spring.datasource.password = pass

    # Hibernate properties
    spring.jpa.database-platform = org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL94Dialect
    spring.jpa.show-sql = true
    spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = create-drop
    spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.implicit-strategy = org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.ImplicitNamingStrategyJpaCompliantImpl
    spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true
```

Note I had the test class in test.java, however I wanted to get the test working in root.package subdirectory, then use @ComponentScan to point to the package tree to scan.

I was looking at the following tutorials to try and get the testing working:

```
http://www.springboottutorial.com/integration-testing-for-spring-boot-rest-services
https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-testing
```

Comment: Does it work at runtime? I mean in controller, not in test.

Comment: @Andronicus Yes, during runtime everything works as intended, including Hibernate generating the proper tables.

Answer (score 1):

When creating mocks via annotations, i.e. `@Mock`, you need to initialize them. The best way to do this is by invoking:

```
MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
```

inside a method annotated with `@Before` so that mocks are created right before invoking tests.

Comment: I inserted 
    @Before
    public void before() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    }
into the test class, and still got the same error